# confusion about some basic definition of function's property

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

If we say that $f(x)$ is continuous on $[a,b]$, does it mean that $f(x)$ is a function only defined on $[a,b]$, or perhaps $f$ can be defined on larger domain?

My consideraion is that: If the sentence "$f(x)$ is continuous on $[a,b]$" only means $f$ is defined on $[a,b]$, then when a function $f$ is defined on a larger domain than $[a,b]$ and is continuous on $[a,b]$, then we have to write that "$f$ is continuous on $[a,b]$" or we have to write "$f\mid _{[a,b]}$ is continuous on $[a,b]$"?

Thanks for clarify~!

Comment: I would say it means that $f$ possibly has a larger domain.

Comment: Thanks for String and Thomas.

Comment: So that I can conclude that if f is continuous on [a,b], then f is continuous on [c,d] which is contained in [a,b], right?

Comment: I saw some books writing that f : [a,b]-->R, does this means that f only defined on [a,b]?

Comment: Yes, the notation $f:[a,b]\to\mathbb R$ means that $f$ is defined on $[a,b]$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just say that $f$ is continuous on $[a,b]$ this implicitly implies that $f$ is (at least) defined on $[a,b]$. You are saying nothing else, i.e. it may or may not be possible that $f$ is defined on a larger set, but you don't say anything about it's properties.